# Magento incorrectly reporting memory limit

Tags: magento, magento2

I have Magento 2.3 installed in Windows 10 using xampp.  I'm trying to set up my cron jobs by running

`php bin\magento setup:cron:run`

I get the error

`setup-cron: Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary`.

When I look at update.log, I see the following two errors

```
[2018-12-06 15:44:37] setup-cron.ERROR: Your current PHP memory limit is 2048M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more. As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit. (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again. [] []
[2018-12-06 15:44:37] setup-cron.ERROR: Could not locate magento/magento2-base/composer.json file. [] []
```

For the first error, why am I getting an error even though my memory limit is higher than the required memory limit?

For the second error, am I supposed to do something in order to create the `magento2-base` directory?  I don't have that directory in my main Magento directory (which is named `magento23`)?

Here is an abbreviated output of `php -i` which contains the `memory_limit`

```
Core

PHP Version => 7.2.12

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini => C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log => C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => C:\xampp\php\ext => C:\xampp\php\ext
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => C:\xampp\php\PEAR => C:\xampp\php\PEAR
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 2048M => 2048M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => no value => no value
serialize_precision => -1 => -1
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => C:\xampp\tmp => C:\xampp\tmp
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
windows.show_crt_warning => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => 1 => 1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
```

Comment: can you display output of `php -i` ?

Comment: I updated the question.  I also see that there's a line in `php -i` that says `Zend Memory Manager => enabled`  Could that cause this?

Comment: nope - but this line might: `memory_limit => 2048M => 2048M`

Comment: open the loaded configuration file (ini file) and you should see memory_limit set to 2048M

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty strange error.

The error message itself comes from here

```
#File: setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PhpReadinessCheck.php
if ($currentMemoryInteger > 0
    && $this->dataSize->convertSizeToBytes($currentMemoryLimit)
    < $this->dataSize->convertSizeToBytes($minimumRequiredMemoryLimit)
) {
    $error = true;
    $message = sprintf(
        'Your current PHP memory limit is %s.
         Magento 2 requires it to be set to %s or more.
         As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit.
         (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.)
         After that, restart your web server and try again.',
        $currentMemoryLimit,
        $minimumRequiredMemoryLimit
    );
} elseif ($currentMemoryInteger > 0
    && $this->dataSize->convertSizeToBytes($currentMemoryLimit)
    < $this->dataSize->convertSizeToBytes($recommendedForUpgradeMemoryLimit)
) {
    $warning = true;
    $message = sprintf(
        'Your current PHP memory limit is %s.
         We recommend it to be set to %s or more to use Setup Wizard.
         As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit.
         (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.)
         After that, restart your web server and try again.',
        $currentMemoryLimit,
        $recommendedForUpgradeMemoryLimit
    );
}
```

with `convertSizeToBytes` living here

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/Convert/DataSize.php
public function convertSizeToBytes($size)
{
    if (!is_numeric($size)) {
        $type = strtoupper(substr($size, -1));
        $size = (int)$size;

        switch ($type) {
            case 'K':
                $size *= 1024;
                break;

            case 'M':
                $size *= 1024 * 1024;
                break;

            case 'G':
                $size *= 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return (int)$size;
}
```

My best/first guess would that -- somehow -- there's some extra characters (spaces, invisible, non-ASCII numbers) in your `memory_limit` value that don't play nice with the logic in this method.

Update: Per the comments -- it's integer overflow with a 32 bit version of PHP.

Comment: I changed my memory limit to 1024M and it's working.  Could it be that 2048 * 1024 * 1024 is overflowing an `int`?

Comment: @BenRubin Good eye! That's very possible -- but only if you're running a 32 bit version of PHP.

Comment: Yes, I am running 32-bit PHP.  That's all that I saw available on the xampp website.